# Can't send mails as root with Mutt through MSTP

Tags: root, smtp, mutt, sendmail

I successfully set up Mutt and SMPT to send to myself some logs through emails.

As user, it works perfectly

However, when I ask through `sudo crontab -e` as `root` to send some logs after running some scripts, I get this error :

```
09 15  * * * /home/user/dir/job_reports.bash > /home/user/dir/log_reports.log 2>&1 | mutt -s 'logs reporting' -a /home/user/dir/plot.png -- 'toto@hotmail.com' toto@hotmail.com < /home/user/dir/log_reports.log

sendmail: the server sent an invalid response
sendmail: the email could not be sent (default account in / etc / msmtprc)
Error sending message, son terminated with code 76 (Remote protocol error.).
Unable to send message.
```

the logs `/var/log/smptc` give this :

```
déc. 14 19:24:34 host=smtp-mail.outlook.com tls=on auth=on user=toto@hotmail.com from=toto@hotmail.com recipients=toto@hotmail.com errormsg='le serveur a envoyé une réponse invalide' exitcode=EX_PROTOCOL
```

Here is the `/etc/msmtprc` :

```
# Valeurs par défaut pour tous les comptes.
defaults
auth           on
tls            on
tls_starttls   on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile        /var/log/msmtp

# compte Outlook
account        outlook
#auth          login
host           smtp-mail.outlook.com
port           587
from           toto@hotmail.com
user           toto@hotmail.com
password       password

account default : outlook
```

I am using these packages `msmtp`, `msmtp-mta` and `mutt`.

I don't know how to go further.

Would you please help with me some hints.

Comment: I added `aliases        /etc/aliases` in `/etc/msmtprc` and created the corresponding 
`/etc/aliases` which includes `root: toto@hotmail.com`

The command `echo 'message' | msmtp toto@hotmail.com` worked. 

However, `echo 'message' | mutt toto@hotmail.com` keeps showing the same error. 

I am pretty sure that it's coming from mutt.

Do you have any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send with Mutt as root mails, we need to create the config file `.muttrc` as mentioned here :

https://www.tecmint.com/send-mail-from-command-line-using-mutt-command/

```
touch /root/.muttrc
nano /root/.muttrc
    set from = "toto@hotmail.com"
    set realname = "dude"
```

It works finely